# Issue creating overlapping multiple pie charts (circular progress bars)

Tags: d3.js, charts

I have 3 metrics to display for a list of companies. I am trying to get a screen with 3 circular bars for each companies.

I am not sure how to format the data and how to parse it to draw the bars. Right now i have only one value displaying three times. I also use a column of the CSV to draw a light gray bar to complete the circular shape. I am sure there's a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish, would love if someone could help! Thanks a million.

Plunk here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/26PSKWrKcSenxAkwHqvh?p=preview

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Company"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {name: name, metric: +d[name]};
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes a good start, but I'd do it a little differently (and a little simplier):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

svg {
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var radius = 80,
    padding = 10;

// set up our 3 arcs
var arcs = [
  d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius - 8),
  d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 18),
  d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 20)
    .innerRadius(radius - 28)
];

// given this csv data
var csv = `Company,score_A,score_B,score_C
Natural Health Trends,10,50,70
Vipshop,90,23,76
Facebook,34,46,87`;

// clean up data
var data = d3.csv.parse(csv, function(d){
  return {
    score_A: +d.score_A,
    score_B: +d.score_B,
    score_C: +d.score_C,
    company: d.Company
  }
});

// an svg for every set of arcs
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".pie")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("class", "pie")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
  
// text in center
svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.company; });

// a g for gray and colored arcs
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(function(d){
    return [d.score_A, d.score_B, d.score_C];
  })
  .enter()
  .append("g");

// gray portion just run 100 %
g.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d,i){
    return arcs[i]({
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: (2 * Math.PI)
    });
  })
  .style("fill", "lightgray");

// colored portion
g.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d,i){
    return arcs[i]({
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: (d / 100) * (2 * Math.PI)
    });
  })
  .style("fill", function(d,i){
    return colors(i);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Pretty amazing, thanks Mark!
And yes, code is much simpler and beautiful.